# How to access Prfile object if I have User object

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile=models.TextField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Profile(models.Model):     
    user=models.OneToOneField(MyUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name="userprofile")
    exam=models.ManyToManyField(Exam, blank=True, related_name="profile")
    education=models.TextField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    branch=models.TextField(max_length=20, blank=True)

# My views.py code
profile=Profile(user=user)
context = {
    "user": request.user,
    "papers":Paper.objects.all(),
    "form":form,
    "profile":profile,
}
return render(request, "demo/user.html", context)
```

I Have user object, I want to access profile object related to that.
Please explain me.

Comment: try posting what did you tried.

Comment: you can access it via `profile.user`